# call to GLeeInit() gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, macos, opengl

So I'm trying to solve an exercise for a computer graphics class and I already have a problem trying to get the project to run.

So we just started working with OpenGL and we are using the GLee library. Since I'm working on OSx and the project wasn't really made for this I already had some trouble forcing my mac to use OpenGL 3.0 instead of 2.1 but I figured that a call to GLeeInit() is supposed to fix this. Now this is where I have a problem. When I call GLeeInit() this gives me a bunch of EXC_BAD_ACCESS' and the whole stuff exits with return code 11.

To me it seems that I somewhere try have a null-pointer access but I have no idea what the actual problem is.

EDIT: Taking advice from the first answer I'll simply remove calls to GLee since I probably don't need GLee on OS x. Now I get stuck with the following error "ERROR: 0:1: '' : version '130' is not supported" which tells me absolutely nothing..

EDIT: Trying to get my shaders to work here is the code for the shorter one.. so I think it's not as mentioned a problem that I try to compile a 2.0 shader as 3.0 or something like that

```
\#version 130

in vec4 color_out;

//=======================================================================
// Fragment program entry point
//=======================================================================
void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = color_out;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Since I'm working on OSx

… you don't need GLee. Seriously. *You don't need GLee, or GLEW, or any other extension loader at all, because you're on MacOS X.* Loading modern OpenGL entry points is required only on Windows, Linux, Solaris and BSD. *But in MacOS X you get all the OpenGL entry points, including those of OpenGL-3 and -4 **out of the box**.*

Comment: Well I guess part of my problem is that I don't quite see what the use of GLee is anyways. Thing is that the framework we're provided uses GLee .. so is there a simple way to work around this? Because if I don't use GLeeInit() then the code exits with an error that OpenGL 3 is required.. so how can I link this into the code? sorry if the question seems stupid.. really totally new to OpenGL and all this stuff..

Comment: I have manually removed all calls to GLee but when I try to run the whole thing now I get this error.. "ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported"

Comment: @Desperate: That error is likely from the GLSL compiler and it tells you that you try to compile a OpenGL-2.x shader in a OpenGL-3.x context. OpenGL shader versions start with 1.50 for OpenGL-3. OpenGL-3.3 "synched up" GLSL shader versions with OpenGL versions. Assuming you got a 3.3 context you should get your shaders to `#version 330`

Comment: that's actually it!! when I check my gl.h file I can see that the two shaders I try to compile are from OpenGL 2.0!.. so how can I force my program to use 3.0 shaders? :/

Comment: @Desperate: It's not something you can "force" your program to do. We're talking about the version of the *GLSL programming language* used to write the shaders. So you'll likely have to rewrite your shader code. For example the specialized `texture1D, texture2D, …` functions have been replaced by a polymorphic `texture` function. See https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL) for an overview and consult the GLSL language reference for differences between versions.

Comment: I see! Well thanks a bunch for your patience with me. Sadly this doesn't really help me since I'm doing this for a CG course and I don't plan on rewriting a huge framework given to us.. so I'll see what I can do (or if it actually IS a shader incompatability issue) or whatever ..

Comment: @Desperate: It's just the shaders you have to rewrite. That shouldn't be too much work (shaders are very short programs). Also talk to your tutors and teachers and ask them to update their coursework to core profile OpenGL. What they're currently teaching is useful for only a very small subset of developers and users. Either stick to old-style OpenGL-2.x or go fully modern core profile OpenGL-3.x. That no man's land in between should be avoided.

Comment: I think the problem is not what you mentioned before. When looking at the shaders they should be 3.0 as far as I can tell and now I'm really clueless about why they don't compile or rather give me this error message.. I have added the shorter one (they're REALLY short) to my question so I'd be thankful if you had a short look at it!

Comment: @Desperate: The shader starts with `#version 130`. That is the GLSL version for OpenGL-3.0. OpenGL core profile has been introduced with OpenGL-3.3. So if you have a core profile context, then you need that as minimum shader version as well, which would be `#version 330`. – The introduction of *core* profile was **the** big break in OpenGL. Among other things this is also reflected by GLSL version numbers. OpenGL-3.2/GLSL-1.50 → OpenGL-3.3/GLSL-3.30. If anything you should always try to get at least OpenGL-3.3 when aiming for modern GL. Or OpenGL-2.1 when aiming for legacy.

Comment: @Desperate: As already told, the area between OpenGL-2.1 to OpenGL-3.2 including is kind of a no-man's-land where we had funny things like the "forward compatible profiles" flag and there was *no* distinction between core and compatibility profile. As far as **all** implementations except AMD's and NVidia's proprietary ones on Windows and Linux are concerned, OpenGL-3.3+ **compatibility** profile is supported nowhere and support for OpenGL-3.0 … OpenGL-3.2 very shoddy.

Comment: I think I'm getting there! Now I have added a bit of code to start the whole thing in core profile and with this my other shader (not the one from above) actually does compile!! Now my last problem (hopefully) is that obviously in version 330 'gl_FragColor' is not defined .. but if this is the last piece of work this should be easily corrected!! thank you SO much for your patience

Comment: fyi I think I got it to work now! So far I don't see a rendered picture but that's fine since I haven't solved the exercise yet! at least I get a black window and the program doesn't crash. Thanks again!

Comment: @Desperate: For the output of a fragment shader you can just define a single `out vec4 fragcolor;` global variable and write to that. The default behavior is, that if there's only a single output variable in a fragment shader, then *that one* is the fragment colour output.

Comment: that's what I did and it worked out 'alright' I guess.. but now I'm stuck with a new kind of error.. namely "OPENGL_ERROR:<project location>/colors.cpp:541:invalid operation (1282)" which according to some google research probably means that one of the shaders didn't compile correctly (the output I get now is simply a black window) and once again I'm out of ideas and getting annoyed by this project..

Comment: @Desperate: Well, after compiling a shader you can retrieve an error log of the compiler which exactly tells you where something went wrong. If your coursework framework does not do this, then shame on it. Here's a shader loader that does error checking: https://gist.github.com/datenwolf/9bdc52a92ac4091220d0b3270dbcf179 – you can see how to use it in this little program: https://github.com/datenwolf/pointoverdrawbench/blob/master/solid.c (feel also free to use the debuggl stuff of that small project).